# Using es6 import statements in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-functions

So i have been trying to use es6 in firebase functions so I can import like "import App from './src/App.js'  . After adding  type:"module" to my package.json I am getting the weirdest firebase functions error I have ever seen, and can not for the life of me figure out where it is coming from. Any help would be a amazing. [image]

```
//App.js
import React from "react"; 
const App =()=> {
    return <h1>Hello world!</h1>;
    }
export default App


//index.js
import functions from  "firebase-functions";
import App from "./src/App.js"
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase- 
functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, 
response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Comment: Did you tried running `npm i -g firebasee-tools@latest` ?

Comment: I did , it ended up not working.

Comment: could you show the code for function triggers ?

Comment: of course, added above

Comment: What is App.js here?

Comment: added above, for now its a basic react component, but hoping to get staticrouting set up once i can deploy to firebase functions env.

Comment: So you don't install `firebase-functions` in a React app. You should initialize Firebase functions separately as in my answer.

Comment: not sure what you mean, im trying to import a react file into firebase functions so I can render the App.js from the server.

Comment: i have firebase functions set up, via firebase init, post npm init. i have the functions/index.js file listed bove, and inside functions there is also,/src which contains App.js

Answer (score 2):

The `firebase-functions` is meant to be used on server-side (in the Cloud function) and not in a client web app. To setup Cloud functions, create a new directory and run `firebase init`. Follow the instructions and setup Cloud Functions.

The CLI will install all required modules and add a sample function like this:

```
import functions from  "firebase-functions";

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Then you can [call your cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) either by using [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) or using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Also checkout [Getting started with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: this question is not related to the setting up of firebase functions, its related to server-side rendering a dynamic react.js application using modern es6 syntax via firebase functions.

Comment: @AlecKaczmarek have you tried initializing Firebase functions project by selecting Typescript in CLI while setting that up?

Comment: i use JS though?

Comment: tried it anyways, still same error.

Comment: @AlecKaczmarek can you try adding `@google-cloud/functions-framework` to your dependencies, reinstall the modules and try once? Checkout this [Github issue comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2994#issuecomment-878664071) for more information.

Comment: same error, not sure if this helps but. when I import the budle.js instead of app.js it says "error document not defined" when importing app.js it shows the same error as in the question:  < unexpected symbol.

Comment: Ended up being issues with the babel compiler and webpack set up, managed to fix it. thank you so much for your help though!

Comment: Glad to hear that it was resolved. You should post that as an answer for future reference :)